# Dynamically created ui-sref link not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

Having a dictionary with which I parse some text on keywords and adds links to a dictionary page. It seems that ui-sref link don't work at all. Here is my function:

```
/**
 * adds links to text instead of an dictionary word
 *  @param  {string} text
 */
Dictionary.prototype.wrapTextWordsInLinksToDictionary = function(text) {
    var i, len, pattern, re;

    // internal wrapping fn
    function wrapInLink(match) {
        var result = '<a ui-sref="app.dictionary">' + match + '</a>';
        // console.log(result);
        return result;
    }


    for (var modelName in this.words) {

        i = this.words[modelName].word.length - 1;

        // starting from plurals and not doing singular if plural is done already
        while (i >= 0) {
            pattern = this.words[modelName].word[i];
            re = new RegExp(pattern, "g");
            text = text.replace(re, wrapInLink);
            break;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

parsing some object in controller:

```
//...
if (typeof vm.disease[propName] === 'string') {
    vm.disease[propName] = Dictionary.wrapTextWordsInLinksToDictionary(vm.disease[propName]);
}
//...
```

and part of a template:

```
//...
<p ng-bind-html="vm.disease.controlDesc"></p>
//...
```

No errors in console, but links are simply not clickable. Can someone give a clue what it could be? Cheers!

Upd when i put `href="#/app/dictionary"` instead of `ui-sref=...` it works fine.

Upd 2 Stateprovider:

```
.state('app.dictionary', {
  url: '/dictionary',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/dictionary.html',
      controller: 'DictionaryStateController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: can you show your $stateProvider?

Comment: @rkalita updated the post

Comment: you need to use `$compile` if you intend to use angular/javascript inside HTML that is inside other variables that you intend to inject via `ng-bind-html`.  I'll leave it to someone else to write a full answer explaining how this works, however, because I don't advocate creating angular logic that uses `ng-bind-html` at all.  This kind of logic is better handled by a directive that modifies the DOM, not DOM injected into variables.  Programming this way is a code smell, and an indication that you are trying to force angular to act like other frameworks.

Comment: @Claies yep, you are quite right - ive been rushing to solve the problem too much here... where i could use a directive

Answer (score 0):

parsing some object in controller:
inject $compile service in your Controller

```
if (typeof vm.disease[propName] === 'string') {
    vm.disease[propName] = Dictionary.wrapTextWordsInLinksToDictionary(vm.disease[propName]);
    vm.disease[propName] =  $compile(vm.disease[propName])($scope);
}
```